# Understanding VS Code IntelliSense/force VS Code IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a Node.js module in which several classes have to be exported. To save time, I decided to make export with a cycle. This is a snippet:

```js
const _erros = {
  MyError1: {
    // fields
  },
  MyError2: {
    // fields
  }
  // other errors
}

class BaseError extends Error {
  constructor (data) {
    // things
  }
}

module.exports = Object.keys(_errors)
  .reduce((acc, className) => Object.assign(acc, {
    [className]: class extends BaseError {
      constructor (message) {
        const params = Object.assign({}, _errors[className])
        params.message = message || params.message
        super(params)
      }
    }
  }), { BaseError })
```

Although the export is well done, VS Code IntelliSense detects only BaseError. Look at this image: [image: proof IntelliSense doesn't work]

As you can see only BaseError is detected: MyError1, MyError2 and all other errors are not showed by IntelliSense.

Is this the proper VS Code behavior or it's a bug? And regardless the answer, is there a way to let VS Code IntelliSense work with exports made with cycles?